# How do i get items in shopping cart using models? (Magento)

Tags: magento

Is there any code with which i could fetch items added to the shopping cart and their count from magento using any models or helpers?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To get your cart object (in session) :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

Then, to get the list of items in the cart :

```
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Then, to get the count for each item :

```
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    echo $item->getQty();
}
```

Comment: i tried this code.. but no result yet.. i am trying this code after user has logged in.. is this code works only before user logs in??

Comment: vrnet's code should work just fine with logged in users. where are you executing it?

Comment: @balanv - you made me doubt so I tried the code :) I works well for logged in and not logged in users.

Comment: Joseph i am executing this code in a phtml file.. will it work only in modules?

Comment: can u help me with some code how to get a single item by id? not all visible items

Comment: try this (if not working, please ask new question):
`$item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load(ITEM_ID);`
Please note: ITEM_ID is the ID of the order item entity, not the product that as been ordered.

Comment: +1 for including $quote->getAllVisibleItems(); instead of $quote->getAllItems();

Answer (score 7):

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($items as $cartItem) {
    echo $cartItem->getQty();
}
```

To get the total count in the cart you can use:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();

  foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $itemCount=$item->getQty();
  }
```

This code will also help...

Comment: how do you get getAllVisibleItems() for this method? Please add to answer

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
$cartItems = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->getItems();
foreach($cartItems as $item) {
    // Do what you want
}
```