# magento $order->getAllItems() return twice the same item

Tags: php, magento, observer-pattern

I'm writing an observer that check every item in a order, at some point I get the items

```
  foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
    //do something
    echo $item->getSku();
  }

  //output
  sku-first
  sku-first
  sku-second
  sku-second
```

but I get twice the same item with the same sku of course, where's the catch? maybe in some configuration file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you want to use `getAllVisibleItems()` instead of `getAllItems()`.

I believe getAllItems gets the configurable along with its associated simple product.

Comment: getAllVisibleItems on Magento 1.8.x works fine. Tks!

Comment: This didn't work for me on 2.2.4, but `if ($item->getParentItem()) continue;` worked!

Answer (score 9):

The option `getAllVisibleItems` don't work

You have to use this code

```
$_items = $order->getItemsCollection();

 foreach ($_items as $item) {
    if ($item->getParentItem()) continue;
    //do something
    echo $item->getSku();
}
```

Comment: `getAllVisibleItems` internally checks that the item doesn't have a parent_item_id, so if it's not working for you, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If `getAllVisibleItems()` is not working, make sure you are getting it correctly:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    echo $item->getQty();
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5512656/922522