# STRANGE...Not able to get cart items in magento on a custom page (only when the customer is logged in)

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.7, cart

Here is the standard code I am using for getting cart items and their attributes which works only when the customer is not logged in. As soon as I log in using my account this script stops working and does not return the items in the cart. Also the cart items count is also 0. But as soon as I close the browser(session ends..) and the script returns the cartitems correctly! Very strange, I have not been able to find out the cause. Please guide, anyone?

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php') ;
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$items = $session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
//$canProceed=0;
echo $productname = $item->getName();   //HERE IS THE COMPLETE CODE:<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',true);
require_once('../app/Mage.php') ;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();


  //Getting buyer's country label

 $bcountry1 =  $_REQUEST['country']; //gets country code

$_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                                ->loadData()
                                ->toOptionArray(false);

foreach($_countries as $_country){
if ($_country['value']==$bcountry1){$bcountry = $_country['label'];}
}
//Fetching vendor for each product

$config  = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig("default_setup");

$dbinfo = array("host" => $config->host,
        "user" => $config->username,
        "pass" => $config->password,
        "dbname" => $config->dbname    );

$hostname = $dbinfo["host"];
$user2 = $dbinfo["user"];
$password = $dbinfo["pass"];
$dbname = $dbinfo["dbname"];


$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname,$user2,$password) or die("Unable to connect"); 
$selected = mysql_select_db("myart2",$dbhandle);


$Proceed=0;

//Getting all products in the cart
//echo $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
// Secret Sauce - Initializes the Session for the FRONTEND
// Magento uses different sessions for 'frontend' and 'adminhtml'
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$items = $session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
//$canProceed=0;
$productname = $item->getName();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',     $item->getSku(), array('manufacturer'));
    $manufacturer =   $product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontEnd()->getValue($product);


 $qry="select * from vendors WHERE company_name='$manufacturer'";
$result =  mysql_query($qry) or die("Unable to run select query");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die("Unable to fetch data");

if( strcasecmp($row['country'],$bcountry)!=0 && $row['ships_abroad']!=1)
{$Proceed=1;$productnames[]=$productname;}
}

if($Proceed==1)
{
echo implode(',',$productnames);
}
else {echo 1; }
?>
```

Comment: tried using firebug to see the request and responce?

Comment: Someone had a similar problem but there is no solution found.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512090/how-do-i-get-items-in-shopping-cart-using-models-magento  Read comment 1

Comment: @NewBee No errors on firebug net tab

Comment: where is that code located? when and how did you call that code?

Comment: @ivantedja the code is located at a custom .php file which I am calling using AJAX from the continue button on the shipping address validation phtml (shipping.phtml)

Comment: added complete code....there may be something else messing with the session.....??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the following four main permutations, and the code works in a stock CE1.7 instance in all cases:

- Create guest quote
- Convert guest quote to customer quote via login
- Instantiate existing customer quote via login
- Merge guest quote with customer quote via login

Adjust the server & app environment params as follows to view & rule out any errors (**edit - added complete script; *note the closing "}"*)**:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
require_once('../app/Mage.php') ;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$items = $session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    //$canProceed=0;
    echo $productname = $item->getName();
}
```

Comment: tried the above code, echos no errors. Is there a problem with my magento install? Thanks for testing for me

Comment: Edited. Try that code exactly - you have a missing curly brace.

Comment: Probably I missed the curly brace here. I have checked the code in dreamweaver, there is no error in the code. Remember, it works for guest buyer, just doesnt work for logged in user...

Comment: Ah, right. Well, there *must* be an issue with your install. I would recommend copying DB, installing a stock version of Magento, and then trying the script above. That way you can rule out DB. One other thing might be the cookie path setting; can any customer information be accessed in the context of this script?